# Retrying firebase token in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I come bringing a query about Firebase in Swift. My app configures Firebase and thus gets the firebase token upon launching. I store the token with no issues and go ahead.

But... What happens if the user launches the app when his device is offline? The app tries to retrieve the token, but fails because there's no internet connection. It tries up to five time and then stops trying.
The app is also locked in the login screen because to be logged you need to have Internet.

Imagine if after the five tries, the device finally gets a connection, and the user logins and enters the app. But I don't have a firebase token and I can't send notifications to the user until he restarts the app!

Can I somehow retry the firebase registration if the user logins without a token?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to solve a problem that isn't actually a problem. A push token won't **always** get refreshed. Here's the description of Firebase's `didReceiveRegistrationToken`.

> This method will be called once a token is available, or has been
>   refreshed. Typically it will be called once per app start, but may be
>   called more often, if token is invalidated or updated.

Furthermore, like Firebase said, once you this method gets invoked, take advantage of it and store the token in your server! When the user starts your app without internet connection, don't worry about it. The user has probably saved the token onto your server. And if the user starts your app for the first time, and without the internet connection, don't worry about it too. He'll get a new one in the next run.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see. I guess I could show the user some sort of message saying that he won't be getting notifications until he restarts the app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After googling more further, I've found that calling `InstanceID.instanceID().token()` does trigger a new retry to get a FCM token if your current token is empty, and returns your current token if you have one. 
I've added that call when the user successfully logins, so that the app can *atleast try* to get a FCM token again.